# how to pipe parsed command into shell interpretor?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I have a 'fancy_awk_script' which parse file names into shell command

```
myself@supercomputer /home/myself $ ls -1 *.MYLOG.csv | fancy_awk_script 
cp 20120607.MYLOG.csv 20120607.MYLOG.csv2
mv 20120606.MYLOG.csv 20120607.MYLOG2.csv
cp 20120605.MYLOG.csv 20120606.MYLOG.csv
...
```

i want pipe above result directly to a shell interpretor, what should I do? something like this?

```
myself@supercomputer /home/myself $ ls -1 *.MYLOG.csv | fancy_awk_script | xargs -E
```

can anyone help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

piping directly into sh works if you don't expect any user input (say it was cp -i).

Answer (score 0):

ls -1 *.MYLOG.csv | fancy_awk_script |xargs -i bash -c {}